# VBA Function to fill empty cells with last non empty value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a simple code to fill empty cells with the last non empty cell as shown in the image:

[image]

```
Function FILL(x, y)

If Not IsEmpty(y) Then

FILL = y

Else

FILL = ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.Column.End(xlUp).Select.Value

End If

End Function
```

The code above return #VALUE! on the empty cells instead.

Comment: Could you show your complete code, e.g. where you call your function?

Comment: You can do this without code. Select the column, F5, Special cells, blank, enter =A2 or whatever first blank cell is, Ctrl and Enter.

Comment: @PaulS, added new img, does that help?

Comment: @SJR, that doesnt work, the empty cells aren't equaly spaced

Comment: can you show the code where you actually call this function please?

Comment: `FILL = y.End(xlUp).Value`.

Comment: You can also use e.g.  `=IF(Y3="";X2;Y3)` and then pull that down.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: Another simple formula `=IF(ROW(A1)>1,IF(B1<>"",B1,OFFSET(A1,-1,0)),B1)`